# Python Dictionary Comment Out a Line not Working

Tags: python, dictionary, comments

I have a python dictionary that I import from another script. For example here is the dictionary that is in another script and loaded in:

```
def Log():
    LogD = {
           'Key': [0, 1, 2],
           'Key2': [0, 1, 2],
           'Key3': [0, 1, 2], # and so on for about 100 records
          }
    return LogD
```

And here is the line loading it in:

```
sys.path.append(r'C:/Whatever')
import Log
LogD = Log.Log()
```

I import it into my other script do some stuff with it and whatever. I also have a module that comments our a line in the dictionary if I want it to be deleted (ignored). That module finds the line and adds a **# comment** to the line in the dictionary like so:

```
def Log():
    LogD = {
           'Key': [0, 1, 2],
           #'Key2': [0, 1, 2],
           'Key3': [0, 1, 2], # and so on for about 100 records
          }
    return LogD
```

But when I reload the dictionary module, the commented line still appears in the dictionary. No idea why, if I don't load the dictionary as a module and include it in my running script the comment works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, are `Key` and `Key2` globals somewhere? If not, are they really meant to be strings? Secondly, how did you reload the module, and did you call the `Log()` function again to get the new object returned?

Comment: why don't you just `pop('key2')` instead on a local copy of the dict ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry added the strings, just was an example. In terms of reloading it, the script runs, adds the comment then closes opening up another script that reloads it.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis that doesn't work as the dictionary has a few hundred records, with several of them commented out. The dictionary reloads fine if I remove the line completed from the dictionary, but I'd like to keep them as old records. If there is no obvious fix to this I am going to create a second dictionary called deleted and move the comments to that which will fix my problem, but I just don't understand why there is a problem.

Comment: Are the `#` characters being added to the file correctly?  Have you opened it in a text editor to check?  What happens when you load the file in the python shell?

Comment: If it is the **script** you wanna modify then ok. If it is just the **dictionary** though then commenting lines out is not the way to go. Plus you say you have a module that does the commenting out. Just use that to `pop` instead. How does that module work?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes they are being added correctly. If i run the dictionary on its own or include it in the script the comment outs work fine. Could it have something to do with the PYC file that is created when importing a module? It shouldn't because it understands when I add or edit a line no problem, just can't seem to handle the comment out.

Comment: And even though i do not agree, are you modifying the file generating the dictionary using the `with` statement? If not, are you flushing the changes??

Comment: @Ev.Kounis the module to 'delete' a line in the dictionary opens the script as a text file, reads the lines and then comments out the line when it finds the key. Saves it. Then runs a new script which calls the dictionary again.

Comment: Another way to do this would be to have some other file where you keep the definition of the dictionary. You can read the contents of that file into a dictionary and then modify it.

Comment: So it looks like if I delete the .pyc file problem is solved. I've included that in script: os.delete(whatever.pyc) after I add the comment and before the import. Now all is good. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since no one answered this I have figured it out. Props goes to someone who commented about PYC not indexing correctly. So I added a

```
os.remove(whatever.pyc)
```

after I edit my dictionary and everything works great.